# What's the translation of "bleisure" in French?

Tags: traduction, travail

Business travel + leisure travel [=](https://www.bbc.com/storyworks/capital/bleisure-bound/bleisure-travel-trend) bleisure travel.

Bleisure [is a](https://www.xotels.com/en/glossary/bleisure):

> term used to describe travel that combines both business and leisure, by not comitting to one purpose solely. People on a bleisure trip, will typically add some extra days to their business trip in order to relax.

What's the translation of "bleisure" in French?

Google Translate and DeepL didn't help.

Comment: Comme je suis blessée d'avoir entendu parler de ce mot ! 
Surely something Eddie Izzard would pronounce /blajʒʊre/ ?  It wounds me...sifflez en travaillant ?

Comment: « Travailler en maillot de bain ». Plus plausible : *— Voyage d'affaire et/plus tourisme. — Voyage d'affaire et touristique* … même si Ngram n'a pas trouvé !

Comment: @livresque En parlant de blesser, c'est aussi la forme d'un mot français, qui signifiait "blessure", et qui n'est même pas dans les dictionnaires ; pourtant il était très courant de 1700 à 1850 : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bleisure%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Comment: @LPH Non *Bleisure* n'était pas très courant au XVIIIᵉ siècle, ce mot n'existait pas plus qu'aujourd'hui. Ne prends pas pour argent comptant ce que Google NGrams renvoie. Il faut toujours le vérifier. Dans ce cas précis, il s'agit simplement d'erreurs de reconnaissance de caractères du mot *bleſſure* où les *S* ont leur ancienne graphie (S long).

Answer (score 3):

Pour *bleisure* (*business/leisure*), *bizcation* (*business/vacation*), et *bleasure* (*business/pleasure*), le GDT donne « [voyage d'affaires et d'agrément](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26529857/voyage-daffaires-et-dagrement) » : « Voyage d'affaires effectué seul, en couple ou en famille, que l'on prolonge à des fins de détente et de loisirs » (GDT). Certainement moins familier et original que les termes en anglais. Le [procédé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot-valise) employé en anglais donne à première vue des résultats méconnaissables en français (*agré/ffaire*) ou des mots qui existent déjà ([*affaire/ment*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affairement)) mais il faudrait y réfléchir davantage.

Answer (score 2):

[Reverso](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/bleisure) shows no translation, merely the use of the American term.

It appears to be the case that for the time being there is no French term and that people in need to mention this concept simply use "bleisure". I deduce that from additional confirmations from some  articles though.

There is apparently an ambiguity at the outset in the definition of this term, an apparent unease in the definition; several dictionaries do not agree with one another.

> ([Word Sense](https://www.wordsense.eu/bleisure/)) **bleisure** (uncountable)
> (colloquial) Travel or another activity that combines business and leisure.

> ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bleisure)) **bleisure** 
> business + leisure = bleisure; it is a portmanteau
> A new breed of traveler is mixing business with leisure on so-called “bleisure” trips.

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/5426/Bleisure))
> **Bleisure**
> New Word Suggestion
> The blurry line between business and leisure trips; the office sends you to Scotland, for example, and you invite your spouse along to get the most out of your corporate-paid hotel room, etc.
> Submitted By: DavedWachsman3 - 27/09/2012
> Approval Status: Reject – not enough evidence

> ([Urban](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bleisure)) Business and leisure combined, commonly used in the hospitality industry.
> A: Are you travelling for business or leisure mate?
> B: I'm travelling for bleisure actually.

There is in this first article below one of the interpretations: "bleisure" as "bleisure trip".

> [Voyages d’affaires : quand le travail peut rimer avec plaisir](https://www.ceservices.fr/voyages-daffaires-quand-le-travail-peut-rimer-avec-plaisir/) Une étude de la société de réservation de voyages Booking.com révèle que près de la moitié des voyageurs d’affaires ont prolongé leur voyage d’affaires pour le plaisir et qu’un troisième prévoit de le faire à nouveau. Le concept de voyage qui combine travail et plaisir est appelé « bleisure » et constitue une tendance croissante dans le secteur des voyages d’affaires.

In the second article I could find that the term is still being dealt with as a foreign term since it is not only used between quotes, but complemented with a capital. The same association of the term with only travel is found again in this article (four occurrences).

> [Hervé Kozar, Transavia : « Travail ou plaisir, pourquoi choisir ? »](https://www.deplacementspros.com/Herve-Kozar-Transavia-Travail-ou-plaisir-pourquoi-choisir_a39460.html) Transavia ne cache plus ses ambitions dans le voyage d’affaires et se positionne en particulier sur le "Bleisure", une tendance de plus en plus naturelle, notamment pour la génération Y, à associer déplacements professionnels et plaisir de voyager. La compagnie filiale d’Air France lance le 5 septembre une campagne de communication de conquête, appuyée par un sondage CSA édifiant.

In this last article 13 occurrences are found of this American term, which shows that there is a serious  intention of using it as a translation. No quotes are used but usage is not consistent (upper-case for the first letter, no upper-case, no article, article); the article is dedicated to the concept of bleisure.

> ([7 conseils pour que les hôtels attirent plus de vacanciers](https://www.revfine.com/fr/bleisure/))

However, the shy emergence of two terms made up from french words  can be found in this article (and they are inexact translations), plus the mention of a would-be synonym, "bizcation", which apparently is considered just as good a candidate for the  translation of "bleisure".

- voyage de plaisir (*It is  really something else (no business, only pleasure)*)
- voyage de plaisance (*same remark as above*)
- bizcation (entreprise vacances)

From what can be read, it is for now  safer to translate "bleisure" as "bleisure".

There are possibilities that do not seem very good, but which finally might become appealing.

- bleisure traveler → voyageur de plaisir, voyageur de plaisance (*It is  really something else (no business, only pleasure)*)
- bleisure trip → voyage d'agrément (*same remark as above*)

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific word for it but when such a business/leisure combination is evoked in French, it is very often associated with the following expression:

> ***[Joindre l'utile à l'agréable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/joindre_l%27utile_%C3%A0_l%27agr%C3%A9able)***. (Wiktionary, bold mine)
>
> 1. to make something enjoyable as well as useful, to make one's work more fun, **to mix business with pleasure**

If you really want something closer and don't mind using nonexistent words, I just coined ***voyages d'affairacances*** for you. It should be reasonably understood by native French speakers.

Comment: That's a omment !

Comment: @LPH That's your pinion!

Comment: It seems to me that what is being asked is not a _definition_ of "bleisure", but a _translation_; nice remark in a nicely concise French form, well known by the way. but not a translation; maybe I'll try to figure out a question to which it is an answer, seems a shame to waste it…

Comment: @LPH I do not provide a definition of "bleisure", none being needed. When no single word exists to translate some word, a periphrasis or anything that convey the idea and the tone can be used. In my opinion *joindre l'utile à l'agréable* fit the expectations, especially as its definition reads "to mix business with pleasure".

Comment: It is only a verbal expression whereas a noun or noun phrase is needed, it is general, as business is a mere possibility, it does not apply to travel in particular whereas the term "bleisure is used only for travel, and finally it is an explanation, but only a partial one (partial definition) of "bleisure". What is "Bleisure"? It is, as the French say, "joindre l'utile à l'agréable". If you have to use that in a translation you have to add quite a bit of text so as to miss nothing.

Comment: @LPH You might have indeed but that would at least lead to something understandable by a native French unlike reusing "bleisure" which is essentially unknown.

Comment: I agree with that, it is concise language that captures an essential part of the concept.

Comment: Faut pas oublier qu'on parle d'un _voyage_ ;  _bleisure travel_. _Voyage qui joint l'utile à l'agréable_ est tout à fait possible et parfaitement idiomatique à mon avis. À mon avis l'emprûnt intégral pourrait mener à la confusion à l'oral avec _blazer_, voire _bled sûr_. -Tu pars en voyage ? -Oui, j'y vais en _blazer_... -Quoi tu n'amèmes pas ton portmanteau ? ahaha

Comment: @viande-à-chien *En déplaçoyage professionagrémentel* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact word to translate this term into French, but it could be translated using a neologism like 'Affaisance' or :

- What are you up to? - I'm taking care of my 'affaises'!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).